# Simple C++ template definition problem

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to C++. Here is the code:

```
template <class T> typename lw_slist {
    // .... some code
    private:     

        typedef struct _slist_cell {
            _slist_cell *next;
            T data;
        } slist_cell;

        lw_slist::slist_cell *root;
};
```

Give this compilation error:

`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A whole new question, a whole new answer:

I think that you will want it like this:

```
template <class T>
class lw_slist {
    // .... some code
    private:     
        struct slist_cell {
            slist_cell *next;
            T data;
        };

        slist_cell *root;
};
```

There is no reason to use a typedef: C++ makes classes and structs automatically part of the namespace.

There is no reason to use lw_slist::slist_cell because slist_cell is already in the current namespace.

The reason that you were getting the error `dependent name is not a type` is that inside a template declaration C++ cannot tell if `lw_slist<T>::slist_cell` is supposed to be a type or a variable. It assumes a variable named `slist_cell` and you have to use `typename` to say otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd better have a deep look at some tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

It's an error because that isn't any kind of declaration at all.

The compiler needs to know if you want a `class`, `struct`, `enum`, `union` or something else. `typename` is not the right keyword to use there.

You are *probably* looking for this:

```
template<class T>
struct lw_slist {
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've updated the question since that if I changed `typename` to `class`, the compiler then said `warning C4346: 'lw_slist<T>::slist_cell' : dependent name is not a type\nprefix with 'typename' to indicate a type`